# What meant by a $k$-chain in a simplicial complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

The book I'm reading defines $k$-chains as follows:

Let $S$ be a simplicial complex, a $k$-chain is a formal sum $\sum n_i\sigma_i$ where $\sigma_i$ are oriented $k$-simplices and $n_i\in\mathbb{Z}$. For $n_i<0$ define $n_i\sigma_i=(-n_i)(\sigma_i)$ where $-\sigma_i$ is the simplex $\sigma_i$ with negative orientation.

I'm not sure how to interpret this definition, the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_(algebraic_topology)#:%7E:text=A%20chain%20is%20called%20a,are%20called%20simplicial%20homology%20groups) for Chains seems to describe a 1-chain as a path between vertices, but what would (using their notation), say, $3t_1+4t_2+t_3$ mean? And how should I interpret $k$-chains for $k>1$?

Comment: Just interpret them as formal sums, as in the definition.

Comment: @AnginaSeng So I'm not supposed to think of them as other $k$-simplices in S? No sort of geometric interpretation for $k=1,2,3$? I don't really understand your response.

Comment: Better that than the misleading idea you have got from the Wikipedia article about $1$-chains.

Comment: @AnginaSeng So these sums aren't supposed to represent anything related to S other than that the notation for them uses some of the notation used for the $k$-simplices in S?

Answer (score 7):

Coefficients in a formal sum count the generators of the free abelian group. If $t_1,t_2, ...$ are 1-simplices, then $3t_1+4t_2+t_3$ is a collection of sticks:

- $3$ sticks at $t_1$,
- $4$ sticks at $t_2$,
- and one at $t_3$.

This does not look like a path. (pic (2)). In homology theory, we focus on cycles  and seldom use 1-chains that look like $3t_1+4t_2+t_3$.

---

$-t_1$ means that a stick is placed on $t_1$, but with opposite orientation/direction.

---

Pic (3) shows that the arithmetic of the formal sums resemble integration paths in calculus, which can be canceled out ($t_1$ and $-t_1$).

[image]

Comment: I see, many thanks.